# JavaScript code does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html

So I made this little thing as I am quite new to programming, but when I open it in Chrome, I am able to type input but then nothing happens. Does anyone know how I can fix this code?
Thanks in advance!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Number Guessing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <b id="bold">Guess:</b> <input type="text" id="guess">
     <input type="submit" value="GO!">
     <script>
      function startGame() {
       function getRandomNumber(low, high) {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low +1)) + low;
        return number;
       }
       var number = getRandomNumber(1,10);
       var guess = document.getElementById("guess");
       for (var i=0;i=0) {
        if (guess>number) {
         guess = document.getElementById("guess");
         document.getElementById("bold").innerHTML = "You're too high, try lower!";
        }
        if (guess<number) {
         guess = document.getElementById("guess");
         document.getElementById("bold").innerHTML = "You're too low, try higher!";
        }
        if (guess==number) {
         alert("You're correct, the number is "+number+"!!!");
         alert("Thanks for playing my game and have a good day!");
        }
       } 
      }
      startGame();
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you think should happen? You have a `submit` button but no form.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of problems, starting with a syntax error.

You have a `submit` button, but no `form` to submit. You really just need a `button`. But, even then, you have to set up a `click` event handler for it.

Then, your loop isn't configured properly.

You also are not accessing the data the user has typed into the textbox correctly - you need to get the `value` of the element.

Your `if` statements should be `else if`.

The `b` element should not be used just for presentation. HTML is a "semantic" language, meaning that you use a tag to describe the meaning (not presentation) of an element. For styling use CSS.

See comments inline below for details.

```css
/* CSS is for presentation, not HTML */
#bold { font-weight:bold; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number Guessing</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Don't use HTML for styling, use it for semantics. -->
    <span id="bold">Guess:</span> <input type="text" id="guess">
    
    <!-- You need a <form> if you have a submit button. For this, you just want a button. -->
    <input type="button" value="GO!" id="go">
    <script>
        function startGame() {
            function getRandomNumber(low, high) {
                var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
                return number;
            }
            var number = getRandomNumber(1,10);
            var guess = document.getElementById("guess");
            
            // Get a reference to the output area just once
            var output = document.getElementById("bold");
            
            // Give the user 3 tries. Your loop wasn't configured properly.
            for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
                // You want to access the data in the textbox. That's the value
                // Also, if the first condition isn't true, try the next and so on.
                // This is done with else if branches
                if (guess.value > number) {
                    output.textContent = "You're too high, try lower!";
                } else if (guess.value < number) {
                    output.textContent = "You're too low, try higher!";
                } else if (guess.value == number) {
                    alert("You're correct, the number is "+number+"!!!");
                    alert("Thanks for playing my game and have a good day!");
                    break; // Get out of the loop because the game is over.
                }
            }   
        }
        
        // Set it up so that clicks on the button run the function
        document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", startGame);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors:

this doesnt work, it wont loop. actually, why do you want to loop?

```
for (var i=0;i=0) {
```

this will run the function once, this means when the user writes the value it wont be checked

```
startGame();
```

the button doesnt do anything, also it has a submit and you don't have any forms:

```
input type="submit" value="GO!">
```

on each if, the conditions are exclusive, use `if/else`

below is a working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Number Guessing</title>
</head>

<body>
  <b id="bold">Guess:</b> <input type="text" id="guess">
  <input value="GO!" onclick="checkGuess()">
  <script>
    var number = 0;

    function startGame() {
      function getRandomNumber(low, high) {
        var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
        return number;
      }
      number = getRandomNumber(1, 10);
    }

    function checkGuess() {
      var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
      if (guess > number) {
        guess = document.getElementById("guess");
        document.getElementById("bold").innerHTML = "You're too high, try lower!";
      } else if (guess < number) {
        guess = document.getElementById("guess");
        document.getElementById("bold").innerHTML = "You're too low, try higher!";
      } else if (guess == number) {
        alert("You're correct, the number is " + number + "!!!");
        alert("Thanks for playing my game and have a good day!");
      }
    }
    startGame();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Although i have no idea about what your program does. you have a syntax error at

```
for (var i=0;i=0) {
```

and also you should bind an event to that button rather than doing a submit.